# Problem in alignment of equation using \begin{align} and \begin{split}

Tags: equations, align

I was trying to align these equation but they are stretching out of the document. Even though I used \begin{split} it didn't work. I don't know why this is so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\prod_1^{k + 1} (s - s_i)=(s - s_{k + 1}) (s^k - (\sum_1^k s_i)s^{k - 1} + (\sum_{1 \le i   < j \le k} s_i s_j) s^{k - 2} + r(s)) 
= s^{k + 1} - (\sum_1^k s_i)s^k + (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} s_i s_j) s^{k - 1} + s r(s)-  s_{k + 1} s^k+(\sum_1^k s_i s_{k + 1})s^{k - 1} - (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} s_i s_j s_{k + 1})  s^{k - 2} - s_{k + 1}r(s)
=s^{k + 1} -(\sum_1^{k + 1} s_i) s^k +  (\sum_{1 \le < j \le k + 1} s_i s_j) s^{k - 1}- (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} s_i s_j s_{k + 1}) s^{k - 2} + s r(s) - s_{k + 1} r(s).
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For one thing, you're forgetting the `&` at alignment points and `\\ `  at line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depend on the width of the text, but it might be a good solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\prod_1^{k + 1} (s - s_i)
&=(s - s_{k + 1}) (s^k - (\sum_1^k s_i)s^{k - 1} + (\sum_{1 \le i   < j \le k} s_i s_j) s^{k - 2} + r(s)) \\
&= s^{k + 1} - (\sum_1^k s_i)s^k + (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} s_i s_j) s^{k - 1} + s r(s)-  s_{k + 1} s^k\\
&\qquad+(\sum_1^k s_i s_{k + 1})s^{k - 1} - (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} s_i s_j s_{k + 1})  s^{k - 2} - s_{k + 1}r(s)\\
&=s^{k + 1} -(\sum_1^{k + 1} s_i) s^k +  (\sum_{1 \le < j \le k + 1} s_i s_j) s^{k - 1}\\
&\qquad - (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} s_i s_j s_{k + 1}) s^{k - 2} + s r(s) - s_{k + 1} r(s).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some corrections of sizes of the parentheses are probably needed. For `split` inside `equation` the usage is analogous, but numbering of lines is different.

Comment: Being a single equation, it's definitely better to use `split` inside `equation`.

Comment: @ karlkoeller Using split inside the equation enviornment is not aligned properly in my case. Any further help?

Comment: @karlkoeller I have partially incorporated your suggestion. However it seems that OP wants `align` as a primary solution.

Comment: @Litun What do you mean? Simply replace `\begin{align}` with `\begin{equation}\begin{split}` and `\end{align}` with `\end{split}\end{equation}` in the code in the answer and you will see the result.

Comment: You should use the `\nonumber` option at the end of the lines the continue. The use of `\left(` and `\right)` can also increase the typesetting

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes it is working, but = signs are not proper aligned in my case

Answer (score 1):

As this is one single equation you should use `split` rather than `align`.  Break the long lines manually via e.g. `\\ &\qquad`.  As `\qquad` is a skip of `2em` this can be put in to a convenient command `\eqbreak`

```
\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}
```

which without argument indents with a `\qquad` space, but with `\eqbreak[4]` will give two `\qquad`s.  Using `mathtools` you can make the wide subscripts under the sums spread under the brackets using `\mathclap`:

[image: Sample ouput]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} (s - s_i)
    &= (s - s_{k+1}) \Bigl(s^k - (\sum_{i=1}^k s_i)s^{k-1}
    + (\sum_{\mathclap{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant k}} s_i s_j) s^{k-2}
    + r(s)\Bigr) \\   
    &= s^{k + 1} - (\sum_{i=1}^k s_i)s^k
    + (\sum_{\mathclap{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant k}} s_i s_j) s^{k-1} 
    + s\, r(s)- s_{k+1} s^k
    \eqbreak
    + (\sum_{i=1}^k s_i s_{k+1})s^{k-1}
    - (\sum_{\mathclap{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant k}} s_is_js_{k+1}) s^{k-2} 
    - s_{k + 1}r(s)\\
    &= s^{k+1} - (\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} s_i) s^k
    + (\sum_{\mathclap{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant k+1}} s_i s_j) s^{k-1}
    - (\sum_{\mathclap{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant k}} s_i s_j s_{k+1}) s^{k-2}
    \eqbreak
    + s\, r(s) - s_{k + 1} r(s). 
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Other changes made:

- all sums correctly indexed,
- `\le` replaced by `\leqslant`,
- larger brackets in the first line for the one big group,
- thin space `\,` add in `s r(s)` constructions.

I have deliberately not made the brackets around the sums larger.

Comment: Many of the fences around the sums ought to be a bit bigger, I tend to use `\Bigl...\Bigr`, as it stands now, especially the `)` *drowns*

Comment: @daleif Generally I would agree with that.  However, in this particular case it seems to get rather unwieldy, hence my last statement.  In fact, I would prefer to reorder so that the multipliers come before the sum and the brackets are unnecessary.